# Create a dictionary from the ouput of the program

Tags: python-3.x, linux, find, caption

This is a Python Program to get all the captions from youtube link:

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/5MgBikgcWnY')
captions = yt.captions.all()
for caption in captions:
    print(caption)
```

and the output of the above program is:

```
<Caption lang="Arabic" code="ar">
<Caption lang="Chinese (China)" code="zh-CN">              
<Caption lang="English" code="en">
<Caption lang="English (auto-generated)" code="a.en">
<Caption lang="French" code="fr">
<Caption lang="German" code="de">
<Caption lang="Hungarian" code="hu">
<Caption lang="Italian" code="it">
```

But I want to get only the lang and code from the above output in a dictionary pair.

```
{"Arabic" : "ar", "Chinese" : "zh-CN", "English" : "en",
 "French : "fr", "German" : "de", "Hungarian" : "hu", "Italian" : "it"}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple

```py
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://youtu.be/5MgBikgcWnY')
captions = yt.captions.all()
captions_dict = {}

for caption in captions:
    # Mapping the caption name to the caption code
    captions_dict[caption.name] = caption.code
```

If you want a one-liner

```py
captions_dict = {caption.name: caption.code for caption in captions}
```

Output

```py
{'Arabic': 'ar', 'Bangla': 'bn', 'Burmese': 'my', 'Chinese (China)': 'zh-CN',
'Chinese (Taiwan)': 'zh-TW', 'Croatian': 'hr', 'English': 'en', 
'English (auto-generated)': 'a.en', 'French': 'fr', 'German': 'de',
'Hebrew': 'iw', 'Hungarian': 'hu', 'Italian': 'it', 'Japanese': 'ja',
'Persian': 'fa', 'Polish': 'pl', 'Portuguese (Brazil)': 'pt-BR', 
'Russian': 'ru', 'Serbian': 'sr', 'Slovak': 'sk', 'Spanish': 'es', 
'Spanish (Spain)': 'es-ES', 'Thai': 'th', 'Turkish': 'tr', 
'Ukrainian': 'uk', 'Vietnamese': 'vi'}
```

Comment: Bro can you say how did you find that output `<Caption lang="Italian" code="it"> ` has an attribute .name and .code??? and whats the type of that output ??? @Łukasz

Comment: Just reading the documentation, sometimes if it’s not clear I use the `dir()` function

Comment: Printing `print(dir(captions))` gives me this output `['__add__', '__class__', '__class_getitem__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']` but I'm still not clear how to get the attribute. Can you explain ??

Comment: You do not get the attribute that way, the `dir() ` function only returns a list of all possible methods/attributes

Comment: This is really off-topic to your question